# Given the perimeter, find the length $\overline{\rm PQ}$ in the following setup.

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

> Let $\overline{\rm AB}$ be a diameter of a circle $\omega$ and let $C$ be a point on $\omega$, different from $A$ and $B$. The perpendicular from $C$ intersects $\overline{\rm AB}$ at $D$ and omega at $E (\ne C)$. The circle with the center at $C$ and radius $\rm CD$ intersects $\omega$ at $P$ and $Q$. If the perimeter of the $\triangle{PEQ}$ is $p$, find the length of the side $\overline{\rm PQ}$.

I solved this question by taking $C$ on the diameter of $\omega$ perpendicular to $AB$. It turned out to be a very simple case where $\triangle{PEQ}$ was equilateral, and thus $\rm PQ = \frac{p}{3}$.[image]

Now this is the correct answer as the question allows us to take $C$ anywhere. But I feel that it doesn't quite grasp the essence of the question. Could anyone help solve it for the general case where $C$ lies at any random point on $\omega$?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Let the radius of the circle centered at $C$ be $r$.

$$\implies \overline{\rm CP} = \overline{\rm CQ} = r$$

Therefore, in $\omega$, $\angle{CEQ} = \angle{CEP} = \theta$

And subtended by $\overline{\rm EP}, \angle{PQE} = \angle{PCE} = \delta.$ $\tag*{}$
Now in $\triangle{PEQ}$, we have:
$$\frac{\sin{\delta}}{\rm PE} = \frac{\sin{2\theta}}{\rm PQ} \tag{1}$$

And in $\triangle{PEC}$, we have:
$$\frac{\sin{\delta}}{\rm PE} = \frac{\sin{\theta}}{\rm CP} \tag{2}$$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$:
$$\rm PQ = {\rm CP} \cdot \frac{\sin{2\theta}}{\sin{\theta}} = 2r\cos{\theta} \tag{3}$$

Now in $\triangle{CEQ}$, we have:
$$\begin{align} \cos{\theta} & = \frac{{\rm QE}^2 + {\rm CE}^2 - {\rm CQ}^2}{2\cdot{\rm QE}\cdot{\rm CE}} \\ & = \frac{{\rm QE}^2 + {(2r)}^2 - {r}^2}{2\cdot{\rm QE} \cdot{2r}} \\ & = \frac{{\rm QE}^2 + 3{r}^2}{4r \cdot {\rm QE}}\end{align}$$ $$\implies {\rm QE}^2 - (4r\cos{\theta}){\rm QE} + 3r^2 = 0 \tag{4}$$

Similarly in $\triangle{CEP}$, we have:
$$\begin{align} \cos{\theta} & = \frac{{\rm PE}^2 + {\rm CE}^2 - {\rm CP}^2}{2\cdot{\rm PE}\cdot{\rm CE}} \\ & = \frac{{\rm PE}^2 + {(2r)}^2 - {r}^2}{2\cdot{\rm PE} \cdot{2r}} \\ & = \frac{{\rm PE}^2 + 3{r}^2}{4r \cdot {\rm PE}}\end{align}$$ $$\implies {\rm PE}^2 -(4r\cos{\theta}){\rm PE} + 3r^2 = 0 \tag{5}$$

From $(4)$ and $(5)$ we observe that $\rm PE$ and $\rm QE$ are the two roots of the equation: $$x^2 - (4r\cos{\theta})x + 3r^2 = 0$$
Therefore, ${\rm PE} + {\rm QE} = 4r\cos{\theta} \tag{6}$

Using $(3)$ and $(6)$, we get:
$$\begin{align} p & =  \rm PQ + (\rm PE + \rm QE) \\ & = 2r\cos{\theta} + (4r\cos{\theta}) \\ & = 6r\cos{\theta} \end{align}$$

Therfore, $$\boxed{\rm PQ = \frac{p}{3} = \frac{1}{3}\cdot\text{Perimeter}}$$

Hence proved.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Let $\,F\,$ be the point of intersection of the segments $\,PQ\,$ and $\,DC\,$ and let $\,G\,$ be the point of intersection of the segment $\,PQ\,$ and the radius $\,OC\,.$

It results that $\,OC\perp PQ\,.$

Let $\,r\,$ be the perpendicular line from the centre $\,O\,$ to the segment $\,PC\,$ and let $\,H\,$ be the point of intersection.

It results that $\,PH\cong HC\,.$

Since $\,\angle PEF\cong\angle FEQ\,,\,$ we can apply the angle bisector theorem to the triangle $\,\triangle{PEQ}\,,\,$ consequently ,

$PE:EQ=PF:FQ\quad,\;$ hence ,

$(PE+EQ):EQ=(PF+FQ):FQ\quad,$

$(PE+EQ):EQ=PQ:FQ\quad,$

$(PE+EQ):PQ=EQ:FQ\;.\qquad\color{blue}{(1)}$

Since the triangles $\,\triangle{EQF}\,$ and $\,\triangle{PCF}\,$ are similar, we get the following proportion :

$EQ:FQ=PC:FC\;.\qquad\color{blue}{(2)}$

Since the triangles $\,\triangle{FCG}\,$ and $\,\triangle{OCD}\,$ are similar, we get the following proportion :

$FC:GC=OC:DC\quad,$

$FC:GC=OC:PC\;.\qquad\color{blue}{(3)}$

Since the triangles $\,\triangle{OCH}\,$ and $\,\triangle{PCG}\,$ are similar, we get the following proportion :

$OC:PC=HC:GC\;.\qquad\color{blue}{(4)}$

From $\,(3)\,$ and $\,(4)\,,\,$ it follows that

$FC:GC=HC:GC\quad,\;$ hence ,

$FC\cong HC\;.\qquad\color{blue}{(5)}$

From $\,(1)\,,\,(2)\,$ and $\,(5)\,,\,$ it follows that

$(PE+EQ):PQ=PC:HC\;.$

Since $\,PC\cong2HC\,,\,$ we get that

$PE+EQ\cong2PQ\quad,\;$ consequently ,

$\text{Perimeter}\left(\triangle{PEQ}\right)\cong3PQ\quad\;$ and

$PQ\cong\dfrac13\,\text{Perimeter}\left(\triangle{PEQ}\right)\,.$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Refer to the figure.

Let $EP=x, EQ=y$ and $PQ=z$.

Also let the radius of circle $C$ be $r$.

It suffices to show that $x+y=2z$.

The $4$ angles marked $\alpha$ are equal.

Also $\angle GCQ=2 \times \angle GPQ$ and $\angle ECQ=\angle EPQ$ $$\implies \beta= \gamma$$

Thus $\Delta ECG \cong \Delta ECQ$ (ASA)

which in turn implies that $EG=EQ=y$

Hence $PG=x-y$ and $FG=\frac{x-y}{2}$

Therefore $EF=\frac{x-y}{2}+y=\frac{x+y}{2}$

Note that in $\Delta ECF$, $EF=EC\cos \alpha=2r\cos\alpha$

Thus  $\color{red}{\frac{x+y}{2}=2r\cos \alpha}$

On the other hand, when we consider $\Delta CPQ$,
we have $PQ=2CP\cos \alpha=2r\cos \alpha$

Therefore $\color{red}{z=2r\cos \alpha}$

The two colored statement implies that $x+y=2z$.